# How to fetch & update custom aspect property in 5.1.1

Tags: alfresco

We have created custom property using custom content model.We need to fetch below information from the custom content model.

1)How can we fetch all Node Ref's which is having the cc:status property?

2)Lets say I will create new namespace[http://www.XXXX.co/model/copy-status/1.0] and new aspect name[cc:new-digeststatus].How can we update all old properties of cc:status to the different aspect name[cc:new-digeststatus] with different namespace?

```
<namespaces> 
<namespace uri="http://www.custom.co/model/custom-status/1.0" prefix="cc"/> 
</namespaces> 

<aspects> 
<aspect name="cc:digeststatus"> 
<title>Status</title> 
<parent/> 
<properties> 
<property name="cc:status"> 
<title>status</title> 
<type>d:text</type> 
</property> 
</properties> 
</aspect> 
</aspects>
```

Comment: What do you prefer: 1) CMIS vs Lucene, 2) JavaScript vs Java?

Comment: I prefer CMIS & JAVA

Comment: Is 'cc:status' property of type or aspect? What is the type or aspect name?

Comment: I am confused. I see an aspect called "cc:status" and a property, which is also confusingly called "cc:status". I do not see an old aspect or an old property.

Comment: updated the content model